# Variable number of columns in pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have two tables.

First table is a dictionary:

```
test_1=> select * from first;
 id | name  
----+-------
  1 | name1
  2 | name2
  3 | name3
```

Second table which is referenced to `first` table:

```
test_1=> select * from second;
 id | number | first_id 
----+--------+----------
  1 |      1 |        2
  2 |      1 |        3
  3 |      1 |        2
  4 |      2 |        3
  5 |      2 |        2
  6 |      3 |        3
```

Now I use pivot to show results:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab('SELECT
  number, name, sum(number)::integer
FROM first
  LEFT JOIN second ON second.first_id = first.id
GROUP BY 2, 1
ORDER BY 1, 2', $$SELECT unnest('{name1,name2,name3}'::text[])$$) AS ta (
     number INTEGER,
     name1 INTEGER,
     name2 INTEGER,
     name3 INTEGER
     );
```

And result:

```
 number | name1 | name2 | name3 
--------+-------+-------+-------
      1 |       |     2 |     1
      2 |       |     2 |     2
      3 |       |       |     3
```

And it's ok.

But now I must manually define columns - `name1, name2, name3...`, but columns are form dictionary table which can be changed.

So my question is - there is any possibility to get columns to pivot dynamically?

Comment: have you considered returning JSON instead of native columns? It's very flexible when you do.

Comment: No, I don't know this technique. Could you provide some example?